# Regex: full match of floating numbers with non-digit symbols

Tags: regex, floating-point, symbols, currency

I was wondering how it's possible to get a full match of positive and negative numbers in a given dataset that also has non-digit symbols. 
I have a bunch of currency transactions and I'd like to exctact just the numeric value.

With the following regex, I get all the numbers correctly but I can't find a way to get the "-" sign.

Any idea why?

```
(\d+)(,(\d{3}))*((?=[,.-](\|$))|(\.\d+))
```

Dataset:

```
null
null
($7.08 CAD)
(-$1.06 CAD)
(€50.03 EUR)
($1,024.38 CAD)
(-$1,024,309.06 CAD)
(€50.03 EUR)
```

Desidered output:

```
7.08
-1.06
50.03
1,024.38
-1,024,309.06
50.03
```

regex example https://regex101.com/r/Nw8EdE/2

Comment: You can't match `-` and skip `$` that comes before it. Maybe using capturing groups will help but  not without a programming language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use 2 capturing groups for the optional `-` and the digits part and match the optional euro or dollar sign in between `[$€]?`

Then you could concatenate the first and the second capturing group as a result.

```
(-?)[$€]?(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)*)
```

**Explanation**

- `(-?)` Capture **group 1**, match optional `-`
- `[$€]?` Optionally match 1 of the listed chars
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `\d+` Match 1+ digits
  - `(?:[,.]\d+)*` Repeat 0+ times mathching either a `,` or `.` followed by 1+ digits
- `)` Close group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EuEIXH/1)